# How to pass Rectangle size available in Millimetre to create Docment using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need to create a PDF file with 100mm X 150mm (Width X Height). To create this I tried to apply following:

```
  var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(new Rectangle(100f, 150f));
```

and

```
float height = 0;
float width = 0;

float.TryParse("100", out width);
float.TryParse("150", out height);

var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(new Rectangle(width, height));
```

But above are generating smaller/ larger size PDF. Please share suggestions that how I can convert the mm to float and make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The measurement used in PDF is called the *user unit*. By default 1 user unit equals 1 point. There are 72 points in one inch. This explains why you document is smaller than expected if you pass a value that is expressed in millimeters rather than user units.

If you want to use millimeters and you don't want to do the Math, you can use the static [millimetersToPoints()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Utilities.html#millimetersToPoints(float)) method in the [Utilities](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Utilities.html) class.